# Convert curl url to pyurl python

Tags: python

curl http://model.dbpedia-spotlight.org/en/annotate  \
  --data-urlencode "text=President Obama called Wednesday on Congress to extend a tax break
  for students included in last year's economic stimulus package, arguing
  that the policy provides more generous assistance." \
  --data "confidence=0.35" \
  -H "Accept: application/json"

Comment: You can try with [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/). First import it from curl, then export it to pyurl.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert curl example to pycurl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799648/convert-curl-example-to-pycurl)

Comment: could someone write an example for it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
url = 'http://model.dbpedia-spotlight.org/en/annotate'
data = {"text": query,"confidence":"0.35" ,"Subject": "Pycurl", "TextBody": "Some text"}
headers = {"Accept" : "application/json"}
res = req.get(url, params=data, headers=headers)
#print res.content
j = json.loads(res.content)
```

Comment: This requires some explanation. You could start with mentioning what `req` is.

Comment: @Vallentin I guess its `import requests as req`, but this user doesn't even bother to mark his own answer as accepted.